# How to dynamically add dash page into flask

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

Following code embeds 2 dash pages (app1 and app2) to flask, app3 is not added.

```
flaskserver = flask.Flask(__name__)
app1 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = flaskserver, ure_base_pathname = "/1/")
app2 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = flaskserver, ure_base_pathname = "/2/")
flaskserver.run()
app3 = dash.Dash(__name__, server = flaskserver, ure_base_pathname = "/3/")
```

Now, I would like to dynamically add new dash pages after flaskserver.run(). Is it possible?if yes, how.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to add new pages after `flaskserver.run()`? You can create them easily [beforehand](https://dash.plotly.com/urls).

Comment: Context is simple. I have 20 trading strategies and need to look at their different combinations. In the main page, I input the weight and click the button to get different P&L summary pages (open in separate windows) and compare them. These PL pages are dynamically generated.